# How do I use or force unity editor code in the runtime/build?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use editor components in the build. I've searched everywhere and they say use this:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    //code here
#endif
```

Which I think is How not to use the editor in runtime. I want the exact opposite.
Is there a way to do it?
or Could there be an alternative to this code to be used in runtime?

```
  var controller = UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController.CreateAnimatorControllerAtPath("Assets/Resources/Animations/AnimationControllers/SAMPLE_CONTROLLER.controller");
  controller.AddParameter("OpenCloseValue", AnimatorControllerParameterType.Float);
  var rootStateMachine = controller.layers[0].stateMachine;
  var myStateMachine = rootStateMachine.AddStateMachine("s_machine");
  var myState1 = myStateMachine.AddState("state_1");
  controller.SetStateEffectiveMotion(myState1, myAnimationClip);
```

Thank You.

Comment: You are referring to preprocessing commands: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-preprocessing-commands

Comment: In short: You can't ^^ They are only available in the Unity editor .. there is nothing you can change about that. Either way it makes little sense to do this on runtime starting with `Resources` being read-only after building ... what hinders you from pre-creating this controller in the editor?

Comment: I can't pre create the controller. Because the user will upload an animation file with the model. Even if I pre-create the controller. How would I assign the animation to it on Runtime? I can't assign it in Editor because well... It doesn't exist yet. It'll be uploaded by user.

Comment: This applies to the **Animation Clip** .. not to the `AnimatorController` .. what you want to do is use an [`AnimatorOverrideController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorOverrideController.html) which allows to maintain the original states but assign a different animation clip to them.

Comment: Oh, so there is a way. Thanks for the help. I'm gonna check AnimatorOverrideController then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before what you are asking for is simply not possible.

The entire `UnityEditor` namespace is stripped of during the build process as it contains functionality that is only available within the Unity Editor itself.

---

It looks to me though what you are trying to achieve is to assign a different `AnimationClip` to a known / existing `AnimatorController`.

This is provided by [`AnimatorOverrideController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorOverrideController.html) which maintains the given animator states but allows to assign a different `AnimationClip` to them.

Simplified example from the API

```
// As usual get the Animator
var animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
// Create an override controller based on the original Animator controller
var animatorOverrideController = new AnimatorOverrideController(animator.runtimeAnimatorController);
// And use this as the new controller
animator.runtimeAnimatorController = animatorOverrideController;
// Assign a new clip to the given state name
// See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorOverrideController.Index_operator.html
animatorOverrideController[STATE_NAME] = someAnimationClip;
```

So you would simply pre-configure an `AnimatorController` completely in the Editor and then on runtime only override your one `AnimationClip` in it.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm looking for. Sorry, I can't give your answer an upvote since my reputation is not that high. But I accept your answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

[`RuntimeAnimatorController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeAnimatorController.html), the class that represents animator controllers **during runtime** in Unity, doesn't allow you to alter controller parameters, layers, or state machines.

The class that you're trying to use there, [`AnimatorController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.AnimatorController.html), is part of the `UnityEditor` namespace, and therefore cannot be used at runtime, hence the other posters mentioning that you need to use the preprocessing command `#if UNITY_EDITOR` to avoid compile errors.

Seems like what you're trying to do here is unsupported.

Comment: Unsupported? There could be a workaround. Its Unity after all. Well Thanks anyways brother, I'm gonna keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Which editor components to you want to use at runtime? I think the answer is that you can't really use components that are exclusive to the editor in a build

Comment: Okay, but If I want to upload an Asset in Runtime. There's a solution like Resources.Load() which is an alternative to the Editor's AssetDatabase. So In Comparison to Editor's CreateAnimatorControllerAtPath Isn't there a method like Resources.Create()?

Comment: @ZaidBinZaheer you can't change the resources folder at runtime because it doesn't exist. When you build, the build files are totally different than the project files. When you do something like Resources.Load() in a build, it functions differently than in the editor.
I am sure there are packages out there that can do what you want to do though.